# Splitting rank 2 trivial vector bundle by Frobenius

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I have an argument about splitting the trivial rank 2 vector bundle. Something is clearly wrong with it but I can't figure it out. Let $\mathbb{P}^2$ be the two-dimensional projective space over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. We have the following short exact sequence of vector bundles:

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-1)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^2 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)\rightarrow 0$$

$\mathcal{O}^2$ lies in the extension of kernel and co-kernel, so it is an element of $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(-1)\otimes \mathcal{O}(1)^*)=H^1(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(-2))$.  By Serre duality this is equal to $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(2)\otimes \omega_{\mathbb{P}^2})^*$. So now let the Frobenius act on this. By $n$ times pulling back the short exact sequence along the Frobenius the cohomology group $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(2)\otimes \omega_{\mathbb{P}^2})$ turns into $H^1(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(2p^n)\otimes \omega_{\mathbb{P}^2})$. If $n$ is large by Serre vanishing theorem this cohomology group vanishes. This implies that short exact sequence splits. So we get a split short exact sequence in the following form:

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-p^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^2\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(p^n)\rightarrow 0$$
But such a sequence cannot be split. Because $\mathcal{O}(p^n)$ will have large global sections which cannot be injected into $\mathcal{O}^2$. So we get a contradiction. I'd really appreciate if someone could point me to my silly mistake.

Comment: When you applied Serre duality, you "changed sheaves without changing $H^i$." I think you should be taking $H^0$ of $\mathcal O(2) \otimes \omega_{\mathbb P^2}$, to which Serre vanishing does not apply.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^2$ is two dimensional. Serre duality send $i$-th cohomology to $n-i$-th one. So sends the first cohomology to the first cohomology.

Comment: All of the $H^1$ groups in this story vanish as we’re doing cohomology of $\mathbb{P}^2$. So can you clarify what it means by let Frobenius act on this trivial vector space?

Comment: @Samir Canning. Well does that imply the exact sequence from the beginning is split? Action of Frobenius means pullback along the absolute Frobenius. Pullback is exact so it turns the sse to another one and we can repeat the argument.

Comment: Yeah it should. I guess I’m not even seeing where your exact sequence at the beginning of the question comes from.

Comment: It comes from a more general construction. If we have a vector bundle $V$ on $X$. Let $P(V)$ be the projective bundle associated to $V$. After pulling back $V$ to $P(V)$, it admits a subbundle $O(-1)$. Now if we replace $X$ by a point and $V$ a trivial 2-dimensional vector bundle on a point we get the above sse.  It is called tautological quotient bundle. Now the question becomes why the quotient has to be $\mathcal{O}(1)$. This follows by checking the first chern classes, and the fact line bundles are determined by their first chern class. (line bundle divisor correspondece).

Comment: Your dimensions are off for this to be the tautological sequence.

Comment: @ Samir Canning You're right! Thanks finally saved me.

Comment: @user127776 Ah right! I kept thinking we were on $\mathbb P^1$ (even while writing $\omega_{\mathbb P^2}$) because of your tautological sequence, which reads as written in the question on $\mathbb P^1$.